# excel auto hyperlink based on content

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've been looking around and can't find if this is possible. I want to know if excel is capable of hyper linking to a file based on input. I have a small inventory spreadsheet where things get moved from one cell to another based on what kit it is in. So the cell content may be manually moved from"sheet1 c3" to"sheet 2 c3". I want the hyperlink attached to that item to made with it. So when I type the name in the new cell it recognizes the content and makes the hyperlink on its own. I have to move things around rather frequently, and I lose my hyperlink to the items full file everytime which means I have to reestablish the hyperlinks each time I move the content to another cell. I hope I explained that well enough. I really hope its something that can be done.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? Is it possible for the items to have named ranges that move with them?

Answer (score 0):

Excel has the `=HYPERLINK(ADDRESS, [DISPLAY])` function which creates a clickable link based on whatever the `ADDRESS` is.  `DISPLAY` can be used to present nicer looking text than the address.

Here you can see it in action with a link to Google.  You can link to files also.

```
=HYPERLINK("http://google.com", "Google")
```

[image: hyperlink usage]

Support page: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/HYPERLINK-function-fb589fd2-3bc8-4f56-bcac-6b8a79d64230